# remove attribute HREF after access the LINK

Tags: jquery, html, href

I want to achieve such e effect...

```
<div id="content"><a href="#MyForm">some text</a></div>
```

after Clicking/Accessing the Link once to have "some text" as a ordinary text... like

```
<div id="content"><a>some text</a></div>
```

So, 1. **How to make that LINK first to achieve the result** and then  **TO REMOVE or DISABLE ATTRIBUTE HREFF?**
Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the html element, try this one:

```
<div id="content"><a href="#MyForm" onClick="document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='some text';">some text</a></div>
```

edit: oops on first post, here some explaination.

By adding the onClick action to remove the element:

```
<a href="#MyForm" onClick="document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='some text';">some text</a>
```

and replace it with

```
some text
```

So after you click the link, you html dom will be modified and look like:

```
<div id="content">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href]').click(function (e) {

    var hash = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    location.hash = hash;

});
```

This assumes these links will always be hashes.

Comment: I need First text to be as a LINK but after ACCESING the result of LINK to disable LINK from the text at all

Comment: Yep. This code will remove the `href` after the `a` tag is clicked on.

Comment: Acctually Not, it removes the HREF atrribute only... I need to have two achivements 1. to achive the LINK result and 2. to dissable the link from text

Comment: Umm, question was _"HOW I CAN REMOVE or DISABLE ATTRIBUTE HREF after first CLICK?"_ This jQuery code does that. What does _"disable the link from text"_ mean?

Comment: THank you for your time and support! But there is problem that I have only the LINK... it DID NOT remove/disable the HREF after the link is accessed